# iOS 7: How to make the status bar selectively clip UITableViewCell content

Tags: uikit, ios7

On iOS 7, the the Weather app's list of cities seems to be using table view cells whose content is selectively clipped by the status bar:

[image: Weather app screenshot]

Each cell has an animated background (clouds in my screenshot) which does show underneath the transparent status bar. However, the text (Montreal 12) is clipped by the status bar.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS7 Status Bar like the native weather app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031483/ios7-status-bar-like-the-native-weather-app)

Comment: If you still interested in that you can go to the duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031483/ios7-status-bar-like-the-native-weather-app