# iOS7 Status Bar like the native weather app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7, statusbar

Does anyone know how can I reproduce a similar effect from the native iOS7 weather app?

Basically, the status bar inherits the view's background underneath, but the content doesn't show up.
Also, a 1 pixel line is drawn after the 20 pixels height of the status bar, only if some content is underlayed.

[image]

Comment: My guess is that it's not specifically a status bar effect, but rather  they're doing a custom transition when the UITableView scrolls up (basically a transparent status bar).

Comment: That's what I was thinking too.
But how could you hide/mask the cell contents?

Comment: Were you able to achieve the effect, I looking for the answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing is to make it through the clipSubview of the view. You put your content into the view and make constraints to left/right/bottom and height. Height on scroll view you check is the cell has minus position and at that time you start to change the height of content (clip) view to get desired effect.

This is a real app you can download and take a look from www.fancyinteractive.com. This functionality will be available soon as next update.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
NSArray *visibleCells = [convertorsTableView visibleCells];

if (visibleCells.count) {
    for (CVConverterTableViewCell *cell in visibleCells) {
        CGFloat positionYInView = [convertorsTableView convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view].origin.y;

        [self clipLayoutConstraint:cell.clipHeightLayoutConstraint withPosition:positionYInView defaultHeight:cell.frameHeight];

        [cell.converterLabel layoutIfNeeded];
        [cell.iconImageView layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}

[self checkStatusBarSeperator:scrollView.contentOffset.y];
}

- (void)clipLayoutConstraint:(NSLayoutConstraint *)constraint withPosition:(CGFloat)position defaultHeight:(CGFloat)defaultHeight {
if (position < 0) {
    constraint.constant = (defaultHeight - -position - 20 > 10) ? defaultHeight - -position - 20 : 10;
} else
    constraint.constant = defaultHeight;
}
```

[image: Starting Page]

[image: Scrolling first item]

[image: Scrolling second itme]

Comment: What is clipHeightLayoutConstraint

Comment: @AVEbrahimi hope I helped you via email.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by setting a mask to the table view's layer. You will not be able however to render the animations inside the cells, but you can do those yourself behind the table view, and track their movement with the table view's scrollview delegate methods.

Here is some informations on `CALayer` masks:
http://evandavis.me/blog/2013/2/13/getting-creative-with-calayer-masks

Comment: Sounds like a very decent solution, and good challenge!
But I wonder, if I apply a mask on the table view's layer, it will also mask the cell's background doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. As I said, you will have to manage cell background by yourself. I can think of a rather simple solution where one cell has the text, the other has backgrounds, and when one is scrolled, the other scrolled too.

Comment: I think this has been done by masking the contentView and leaving the backgroundView with the animation. Everything in the contentView will get hidden.

Comment: Perhaps minimizing the frame while having it's content clipped might do the trick as well. Did you get any process? I am currently figuring out the pinch to details view transition.

Comment: @Mark What about an interactive transition between two collection view controllers' layout, controlled by a gesture recognizer?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5:**

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard let visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells as? [TableViewCell] else { return }

    let defaultClipHeight: CGFloat = 24
    let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = UIApplication.statusBarHeight
    
    if !visibleCells.isEmpty {
        for cell in visibleCells {
            let topSpace = cell.frame.size.height - defaultClipHeight - cell.clipBottomConstraint.constant
            let cellOffsetY = tableView.contentOffset.y - cell.frame.origin.y + statusBarHeight
            
            if cellOffsetY > topSpace {
                let clipOffsetY = cellOffsetY - topSpace
                let clipHeight = defaultClipHeight - clipOffsetY
                
                cell.clipHeightConstraint.constant = max(clipHeight, 0)
            } else {
                cell.clipHeightConstraint.constant = defaultClipHeight
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Starting Page:
[image: Starting Page]

Scrolling First Item:
[image: Scrolling First Item]

Scrolling Second Item:
[image: Scrolling Second Item]